# React native inaccurate device width division question

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i've come across a problem trying to create a grid by dividing the device width.

When trying to make 7 Views next to each other in a row by doing Dimensions.get('window').width / 7, it calculates only 6 in a row and because the parent container has flex: wrap, it drops the 7th View in a second row. This only happens on iPhone devices specifically iPhone X (12.1), it calculates it perfectly on iPad. Am i missing something in the calculations or is it a known issue?

Comment: Please add your .js code

Answer (score 0):

i'think doesn't use width/7 use this

`<View style={{flex : 1}}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} /> //7x
      </View>`

or use react-native-grid and

```
<Grid><Row/></Grid>
```